# Why are there 3 parsing conflicts in my tiny grammar?

Tags: context-free-grammar, lemon

```
//complete
start ::= template.

//template
template ::= template_elements.
template ::= template template_elements.
template ::= .

//template elements
template_elements(res) ::= COMMENT. 
template_elements(res) ::= tag(t). 

//tag
tag(res) ::= LDEL exp(e) RDEL. 

//exp
exp(res) ::= value(v). 
exp(res) ::= exp(e1) OP(o) exp(e2).

//value
value(res) ::= variable(v). 

//variable
variable(res) ::= DOLLAR ID(i).
```

Anyone knows where the conflicts locate?

**UPDATE**

If I delete `exp(res) ::= exp(e1) OP(o) exp(e2).`,there'll be only two conflicts,but I don't know why this is causing conflict...

**UPDATE2**

Why it's OK [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#JAXruTdKQ_g/trunk/development/lexer/smarty_internal_templateparser.y):

```
template ::= template_elements.
template ::= template template_elements.
template ::= .
```

Comment: Try deleteing one rule at a time, and see what happens.

Comment: Err, what exactly does this question have to do with yacc?  You seem to be quoting some advanced BNF-like parameterized grammar language...

Comment: I remember from my old days in CS that `exp(e1) OP(o) exp(e2)` is likely to cause an ambiguity for an expression like `exp(e1) OP(o) exp(e2) OP(o) exp(e3)`.  Not sure if that's what it's referring to?

Comment: @mellamokb ,how to get rid of the ambiguity then?

Comment: @DigitalRoss ,should be lemon.

Comment: See http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/lemon.html.  I think you have to use the `%left` directive to mark it as left-associative?  I'm really over my head on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your exp ambiguity, set the precedence and associativity -- see the [documentation](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/lemon.html) under Precedence Rules.

Lemon can handle left recursion, but your `template` rule should be

```
template ::= template template_elements.
template ::= .
```

Because `template` can be empty, you don't need the `template ::= template_elements` case.

What errors do you get after making those changes?

Comment: After `%left` and this change,there's only 1 conflict now..`template ::= template_elements.`

Comment: Try getting rid of the empty template rule, `template ::= .` and allowing `template_elements` to be empty.

Comment: for the exp rule, it didn't know whether `v op v op v` was `(v op v) op v` or `v op (v op v)` until you told it what the associativity was. For the template rule it didn't know if a single template element was the first line of your original rule, or the second with an empty value for `template`. I'm not certain why there were three ambiguities originally.

Comment: But why it works here:http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#JAXruTdKQ_g/trunk/development/lexer/smarty_internal_templateparser.y ?

Comment: I just tried that large .y file,and there are 416 conflicts...How can it still pass compiling and generate the code?

Comment: Ambiguities in the grammar don't necessarily mean that it won't work -- if your operators are associative then it doesn't matter whether the parser parses them with left or right associativity, for instance.